# Jenkins and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

So I have a MEAN application up and running and Im looking into a continuous integration solution.  I have successfully gotten Jenkins up and running with web hooks that grab my project from a bitbucket repo when a merge happens to master.

Right now I do not have any tests so Jenkins just runs some shell commands that 'deploys' the server. Which is great. My goal would be to have this run tests and fail a deploy if they fail.

So my problem is that the build never completes. My goal would be to when it completes it will keep the server running or deploy it and keep it running.
Here are the shell commands I run one the build is kicked off.

```
npm install
npm install bower
bower install
npm install grunt-cli
grunt prod
node server
```

And it successfully runs the server and such but it just hangs up after the `node server`  command is executed

How do I make it so Jenkins sees this as successful and then deploys it? I have crawled the internet with no much luck.

**EDIT:**
So looking at some docs and such. I would need to configure my tests to run when the build gets ran. If there are not tests then it passes (by default)... So what I need is when that happens,  jenkins needs to run a deploy script. After looking around in jenkins I am still unable to figure out how to do so.

**EDIT #2**
So moving those shell script out of the build allows it to finish and is 'successful' since no tests are present. I see that jenkins keeps the project in a workspace directory. Is there a way to get jenkins to deploy from there or some kind of other application to deploy that build in that workspace?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was something simple but im not sure if its best practice..

Jenkins has the webhook to my bitbucket repo and watches for pulls into master. This then kicks off my jenkins build which it runs

```
npm install bower
bower install
npm install grunt-cli
grunt prod
```

which builds the project. Then I installed nodemon which watches the last "successful build" folder run the server from there. When it gets refreshed the server restarts. This seems to run pretty smoothly so far.